# ExtJS radio button value retrieval

Tags: extjs

I need to retrieve the value of the radio button checked and send it to the form as parameters. I have written the below block of code but every time it just passes the first value. Could somebody help.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.getCmp('myButton').setHandler(function(){

    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title:    'Hello', 
        msg:      'Please choose one? <br></br> Select: '+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="Yes" checked /> Yes'+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="No" /> No',
        buttons:  Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        fn: function(btn) {
            if( btn == 'ok') {
                alert(Ext.get('newrate').getValue());
                    var form = Ext.getCmp("MyForm").getForm();
                    form.getEl().dom.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/peer.online.MyForm.grid.action?mode=StornoDX&value="+Ext.get('newrate').getValue();
                    form.getEl().dom.method="POST";
                    form.getEl().dom.submit();
                }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its **not a Extjs Radio button** and `Ext.get()` is used to get html element with `id` as its input. In your case its **a html element** with name as `"newrate"`. So you can get value of checked radio button using (**For Browser > IE8**)`document.querySelector()`, like this:

```
document.querySelector('[name=newrate]:checked').value
```

**Sample Working Code:**(**For Browser > IE8**)

```js
Ext.application({
      name: 'Fiddle',

      launch: function() {
      Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title:    'Hello', 
        msg:      'Please choose one? <br></br> Select: '+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="Yes" checked /> Yes'+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="No" /> No',
        buttons:  Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        fn: function(btn) {
            if( btn == 'ok') {
                alert(document.querySelector('[name=newrate]:checked').value);
                  
                }
        }
    });
        }
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

As **IE8 or less** browser doesn't support `:checked` CSS3 selector. So we need to loop through all the radio buttons and find the checked radio button and get its value:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("newrate");
   for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {         
      if(buttons[i].checked) {
         alert(buttons[i].value);
         break;
      }
   }
```

**Sample Working Code:**(**For All Browsers**)

```js
Ext.application({
      name: 'Fiddle',

      launch: function() {
      Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title:    'Hello', 
        msg:      'Please choose one? <br></br> Select: '+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="Yes" checked /> Yes'+
        '<input type="radio" name="newrate" value="No" /> No',
        buttons:  Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        fn: function(btn) {
            if( btn == 'ok') {
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("newrate");
   for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {         
      if(buttons[i].checked) {
         alert(buttons[i].value);
         break;
      }
   }                      
                }
        }
    });
        }
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit for the answer. One more question here, as I see this has some browser limitations. It works fine for me on Chrome but on IE8 I face issues. Is there any alternative to have it working on all browsers?

Comment: Ohh..the problem is IE 8 doesn't support `:checked` CSS selector. So we need to loop through the radio button and find the checked value. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That's great!! Could you accept the answer,it will help othersalso